# How to handle multiple Strings in a Textarea

Tags: java, libgdx

I am currently developing a game to teach kids coding of some sort. My problem is that i can only "acces" or use the first String in my text area.I want to implement a solution which runs the textarea as actions for my game actor.

```
public void show() {
    spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch();
    texture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("images/player.png"));
    sprite = new Sprite(texture);
    camera = new OrthographicCamera();
    camera.setToOrtho(false, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
    camera.update();
    //player = new playerClass(1, 1);
    gameMap = new TiledGameMap();
    textInputField = new TextInputField();
    sprite.setSize(32,32);
    sprite.setX(2*32);
    sprite.setY(2*32);
    touch.set(sprite.getX(),sprite.getY());


    textInputField.textButton.addListener(new ClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void clicked(InputEvent e, float x, float y){
            for (String line : textInputField.textArea.getText().split("\\n")){
            textInputField.textButton.setText("Compiling!");



            String textStr = textInputField.textArea.getText();
            Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("\\d+").matcher(textStr);
            matcher.find();
            int i = Integer.valueOf(matcher.group());


                textStr = line;
                if(line.equals("walk("+ i + ");")) {
                    touch.set(sprite.getX()+i*32,sprite.getY());
                    System.out.println(i);

                }
                if(line.equals("walk -"+ i)) {
                    touch.set(sprite.getX()+-i*32,sprite.getY());
                    System.out.println(i);
                }
```

Comment: Can you post definition for TextInputField class?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/7wMYt1y8